# PHP if statement with a MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

Is there a way to do an `if` statement like this:

```
if ($password == mysql_query("SELECT password from member WHERE id = $id")) {

// f00

}
```

So what I mean is, if it is possible and/or good practice to have a short query in your `if`, instead of extracting it from your DB first.

Thanks!

Comment: You might want to consider, Not doing it like that. What if mysql_query fails? What happens then? I would move the query-execution above the if-statement.

Comment: You must parse result from query to array or object. Then check

Comment: you have a SQL-injection hole in that code, change `WHERE id = $id"` to `WHERE id = '$id'"` *(note the single quotes around `$id`, otherwise `mysql_real_escape_string()` will not protect you.

Comment: Why aren't people using [PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) instead of the horribly dangerous `mysql_query` function?

Answer (score 1):

mysql_query returns a resource so it wont work

Comment: He knows that, he is wondering if there is a similar single-statement that will accomplish what he's after.

Comment: it was not clear to me, based on what he posted, that he knew it. Looking at the other answers\comments, I'm not the only one either.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend it. If there is an error in the SQL, if you can't connect to the server, if there are no rows returned, or if there are any other errors then you'd have some big problems.

Answer (score 0):

Sure it's possible but it's not a good idea.

Consider if you were using a database abstraction layer instead of basic php_mysql like  [adodb](http://adodb.sourceforge.net/)

you could easily have:

```
   if($password == $DB->GetOne('Select password from member where id = '.$ID)){
        //do something
   }
```

However if the query failed or otherwise returned anything you were implicitly expecting you could have unforeseen errors.

You should encapsulate database output and database queries so that if they fail, they fail gracefully and do not have weird side effects that could be a pain to track down later.